# Traffic not tunneling through NetworkManager VPN Client, but vpnc works fine

Tags: cisco, tunnel, traffic, vpnc

I'm trying to connect to a VPN using the NetworkManager Cisco VPN client, and everything seems to be going fine when connecting. I click connect, the NM icon on the top panel displays the connecting animation, and NotifyOSD displays the banner informing me that I've successfully connected (i.e., the VPN server displays it's welcome message), and I get a little padlock next to the wireless connection icon. Yet traffic doesn't go through the VPN. My IP address is still the same, and the ads that appear on the different websites I browse recognize my location.

However, when I connect using `sudo vpnc MyVPNSettingsFile.conf` from the terminal, I do it successfully here, but this time my traffic does get tunneled through the VPN. What causes this different and what can I tweak to make the NetworkManager client work? (It's not the end of the world if I have to do it through the command line, but the nm-applet integration gives me that padlock icon, and the fewer clicks take less time than opening a terminal and getting the command right.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide us some log files?
As far as I know you have to run `ipseclog logfilename` and then start vpnc. It will connect to ipseclog for the logging.

Answer (score 1):

hmm i don't use cisco vpn but maybe since its connected if seems strange that it doesn't work even though it claims the vpn is up.

could you compare the routing tables when connecting through terminal vs gui?

just type
**route -n** 
in the terminal

if they differ
paste them here.

Another thing to check , what about permissions for certificates etc?
I've noticed that openvpn at least refuses to work from the applet if the permissions are to "loose" compared to if i run the vpn from the terminal